# Prove that $H<G\Rightarrow |H|\le \left\lfloor \frac{|G|}{2}\right\rfloor$ without Lagrange's theorem.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Suppose we do not have yet the notion of coset, and thence Lagrange's theorem either. So, if $G$ is a finite group and $H<G$, we just know that $H$ is a nonempty, proper, *closed* subset of $G$.

> (How) Can we prove, in this framework, that $|H|\le \left\lfloor \frac{|G|}{2} \right\rfloor$?

Some facts we might be using are, e.g. (here $f$ denotes group's operation):

- $f(H\times H) = H$
- $f(H\times (G\setminus H))= G\setminus H$

Based on this, I've tried to come up with some equation/inequality involving the cardinalities of the "level sets" $L_a^{H×H}:=\{(h,h')∈H×H\mid hh'=a\}$ for $a∈H$, and $L_a^{H×H^c}:=\{(h,c)∈H×H^c\mid hc=a\}$ for $a∈H^c$ (where $H^c:=G\setminus H$), but unsuccessfully.

---

**Addendum**. Some more stuff, just to see whether the idea may get to somewhere. We have:

\begin{alignat}{1}
|H|^2 &= \sum_{a\in H}|L_a^{H\times H}| \\
&= |H|+\sum_{a\in H\setminus\{e\}}|L_a^{H\times H}| \\
\end{alignat}

whence:

\begin{alignat}{1}
|H|\cdot(|H|-1) &= \sum_{a\in H\setminus\{e\}}|L_a^{H\times H}| \\
\tag 1
\end{alignat}

Moreover:

\begin{alignat}{1}
|H||H^c| &= \sum_{a\in H^c}|L_a^{H\times H^c}| \\
\tag 2
\end{alignat}

By $(1)$ and $(2)$, we get both:

\begin{alignat}{1}
|H|\cdot(|G|-1) &= \sum_{a\in H^c}|L_a^{H\times H^c}| + \sum_{a\in H\setminus\{e\}}|L_a^{H\times H}| \\
\tag 3
\end{alignat}

and:

\begin{alignat}{1}
|H|\cdot(|H^c|-|H|+1) &= \sum_{a\in H^c}|L_a^{H\times H^c}| - \sum_{a\in H\setminus\{e\}}|L_a^{H\times H}| \\
\tag 4
\end{alignat}

*If* from $(3)$ and/or $(4)$ we could deduce that $|H|\mid |G|$ (or, equivalently, $|H|\mid |H^c|$), we'd get actually more than what I originally asked, namely a "coset-free" proof of Lagrange's theorem.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @verret I've tried to come up with some equation involving the cardinalities of the "level sets" $L_a^{H\times H}:=\{(h_1,h_2)\in H\times H\mid h_1h_2=a\}$ for $a\in H$, and $L_a^{H\times H^c}:=\{(h,c)\in H\times H^c\mid hc=a\}$ for $a\in H^c$ ($H^c:=G\setminus H$), but unsuccessfully.

Answer (score 6):

Fix $x \in G$ with $x \not \in H$. Consider the set
$$
S = \{xh \mid h \in H\}. 
$$
The cardinality of $S$ is equal to the cardinality of $H$ since whenever $xh = xh'$ we have $h = h'$. Also, nothing in $S$ is in $H$ since $xh = h' \Rightarrow x = h'h^{-1} \in H$.

So the size of $G$ is at least the size of $S$ plus the size of $H$, i.e. at least twice the size of $H$.

I don't know if this proof is what you want since of course $S$ is just a coset of $H$.

Comment: "Fix $x \in H$ with $x \not\in H$."  No such $x$ exists.  (I assume the first "$H$" should be a "$G$".  Wouldn't it be easier to write "Fix $x \in G \smallsetminus H$."?)

Comment: @EricTowers looks like an editor fixed it, thanks!